# how to draw an X on an image with imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick

I'm attempting to make this image with imagemagick. I'd like the line to start and end on corners (and the dimensions of the image are not known). Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [FX escape](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/transform/#fx_escapes) format to determine image dimensions, however FX commands are not recognized by the draw interpreter. If you wish to use [-draw](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#draw), it would be easier to generate the X format in one command, and apply with another.

```sh
CROSS=$(\
    convert source.png \
    -format "line 0 0 %[fx:w] %[fx:h], line 0 %[fx:h] %[fx:w] 0" \
    info:\
)
convert source.png -stroke black -strokewidth 4 -draw "$CROSS" destination.png
```